# Is Visual Studio recursive_directory_iterator.pop() broken?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std

Given an example directory tree for testing:

```
Root
   A
      A1
      A2
   B
      B1
      B2
```

I wish to recursively enumerate the directories, but skip the processing of directory A completely.

According to the MSDN documentation code something like the following should do the job:

```cpp
void TestRecursion1()
{
   path directory_path("Root");
   recursive_directory_iterator it(directory_path);

   while (it != recursive_directory_iterator())
   {
      if (it->path().filename() == "A")
      {
         it.pop();
      }
      else
      {
         ++it;
      }
   }
}
```

...it does not. MSDN for recursive_directory_iterator.pop() states

```
If depth() == 0 the object becomes an end-of-sequence iterator. 
Otherwise, the member function terminates scanning of the current
(deepest) directory and resumes at the next lower depth.
```

What actually happens is that due to a short circuit test in pop() if 'depth == 0' nothing happens at all, the iterator is neither incremented nor does it become the end of sequence iterator and the program enters an infinite loop.

The issue seems to be that semantically pop() is intended to shunt processing of the tree to the next level higher than the current level, whereas in this example I wish to skip processing of A and continue processing at B. The first problem is that both these directories (A and B) exist at the same level in the tree, the second problem is that this level is also the top level of the tree so there is no higher level at which to resume processing. All that said it still seems like a bug that pop() fails to set the iterator to the end-of-sequence iterator thus causing an infinite loop.

After this testing I reasoned that if I can't pop() A directly, I should at least be able to pop() from any child of A and achieve a similar result. I tested this with the following code:

```cpp
template<class TContainer>
bool begins_with(const TContainer& input, const TContainer& match)
{
   return input.size() >= match.size()
      && equal(match.begin(), match.end(), input.begin());
}

void TestRecursion2()
{
   path base_path("C:\\_Home\\Development\\Workspaces\\Scratch \\TestDirectoryRecursion\\bin\\Debug\\Root");
   recursive_directory_iterator it(base_path);

   while (it != recursive_directory_iterator())
   {
      string relative_path =  it->path().parent_path().string().substr(base_path.string().size());
      cout << relative_path << "\n";

      if (begins_with(relative_path, string("\\A")))
      {
         it.pop();
      }
      else
      {
         cout << it->path().filename() << " depth:" << it.depth() << "\n";
         ++it;
      }
   }
}
```

Here I test every item being processed to determine whether its parent is Root\A, and if it is call pop(). Even this doesn't work. The test correctly identifies whether a node in the tree is a child of A and calls pop() accordingly, but even at this deeper level pop() still fails to increment the iterator, again causing an infinite loop. What's more, even if this *did* work it would still be very undesirable since there is no guarantee of the order in which sub nodes are enumerated, so despite the test to check whether a particular node is a child of A because those nodes might be indirect children you could still end up processing a goodly amount of A anyway.

I think my next course of action is to abandon use of this recursive_directory_iterator and drive the recursion manually using a standard directory_iterator, but it seems as if I should be able to achieve what I need more simply with the recursive_directory_iterator but I'm getting blocked at every turn. So my questions are:

Is the recursive_directory_iterator.pop() method broken?

If not how do I use it to skip the processing of a directory?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the code you want more like the following, using [`disable_recursion_pending()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/disable_recursion_pending)?

```
   while (it != recursive_directory_iterator())
   {
      if (it->path().filename() == "A")
      {
         it.disable_recursion_pending();
      }
      ++it;
   }
```

Comment: That does work but disable_recursion_pending is only available in VS2015 and I'm trying to do this in VS2012. Documentation for disable_recursion_pending states that it "stores true in no_push", VS2012 has a no_push method instead, but the effect of that is to disable recursion in every subsequent tree node not just the one you call it on. This also seems totally broken because that's not how the Boost implementation that the tr2 filesystem library is based on behaves. In the Boost implementation no_push sensibly only applies to the node the iterator is currently pointing to.

Comment: The description of `pop()` that you quote is for VS2015 - the description of `pop()` for VS2012 says only `Discontinues reading in the current subdirectory and increments the iterator` - with no guarantees about what will happen subsequently.

Comment: You're right about that, I'm testing this in VS2012 and VS2015 and I copied the documentation snippet from the wrong page. It still doesn't increment the iterator in VS2012 though.

Comment: Personally I think that expecting the VS2012 implementation to work is asking too much.  And expecting it to work the same as Boost is asking way more.  (For example, as you point out, `no_push()` doesn't even take an argument, so the even the API is already at odds with even the first revision of the TR2 proposal.)